# the equivalent of BlocListener in GetX

Tags: flutter, bloc, flutter-getx

is there any equivelant to BlockListener in Getx, like to show a snackbar for example depending on state... like this example from Bloc pattern

```
body: BlocConsumer<PhotoBloc, PhotosState>(
        listener: (context, state) {
             if(state is PhotoErrorState) {
               return ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                 SnackBar(content: Text(state.message))
               );
             }
        },

        builder: (context, state) {
          if (state is PhotoLoadingState) {
            return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(),);
          } else if (state is PhotoLoadedSuccessfullyState) {
            return Card(
              child: ListView.builder(
                itemCount: state.photos.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, i) {
                  return ListTile(
                    leading: CircleAvatar(child: Image.network(state.photos[i]
                        .url),),
                    title: Text(state.photos[i].title),

                    onTap: () {
                      context.read<NavigationCubit>().showPhotoDetails(state.photos[i]);
                    },
                  );
```

Comment: @Loren.A is right also you can use Obx. You can check the document right here https://pub.dev/packages/get#state-management.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Workers](https://github.com/jonataslaw/getx/blob/master/documentation/en_US/state_management.md#workers) are the Getx way of listening to any observable object. The `ever` function gets called any time an observable object changes.

Lets say you really want to make it feel like `bloc` and you want to setup an observable enum so its similar to `state.whateverState...`

You could do something like this by setting the listener in the `onInit` of the controller:

```
enum Status { none, running, stopped, paused }

class Controller extends GetxController {
 Rx<Status> status = Status.none.obs;

   @override
  void onInit() {
    super.onInit();
    ever(
      status,
      (value) {
        if (value == Status.running) {
          Get.snackbar('State Updated', 'Running');
        }
        if (value == Status.none) {
          Get.snackbar('State Updated', 'None');
        }
        if (value == Status.stopped) {
          Get.snackbar('State Updated', 'Stopped');
        }
        if (value == Status.paused) {
          Get.snackbar('State Updated', 'Paused');
        }
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Then from anywhere in the app you could do something like this:

```
 Get.find<Controller>().status.value = Status.paused;
```

And that will show the paused snack bar.

Comment: What if I need to do something with the context? The worker is only accessible in the controller. I'm currently using AutoRoute so I can't use Get's navigation, which means I need the context, and I can't find a way to do this. With bloc's listenWhen I was able to do things with the context, because it was trigger inside the view. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: In most cases you can access the current context with `Get.context`

Answer (score 0):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/state_manager.dart';

typedef BlocWidgetListener<S> = void Function(BuildContext context, S state);

class GetListener<T> extends StatelessWidget {
  const GetListener({
    Key? key,
    required this.valueRx,
    required this.listener,
    required this.child,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final RxInterface<T> valueRx;
  final BlocWidgetListener<T> listener;
  final Widget child;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    ever<T>(valueRx, (value) => listener.call(context, value));
    return child;
  }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).